# Diference between celldoubleclick and cellmousedoubleclick?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm try to understand which is the difference between celldoubleclick and cellmousedoubleclick? Which is better to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A discussion from [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/35af1871-5898-4d19-b853-1e259a2b76fc/what-is-the-difference-between-celldoubleclick-and-cellmousedoubleclick?forum=winformsdatacontrols):

> i think that CellMouseDoubleClick reffers to any button, while
>   CellDoubleClick is only for the left mouse button

Comment: From [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmousedoubleclick.aspx): This event occurs when the user double-clicks using any of the mouse buttons. So this seems the correct interpretation.

Comment: If i will use contexmenuscript in datagridview, is better using CellDoubleClick?